# jQuery not removing element using Rails 3 Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I can successfully `create` an element with Ajax. Now I'm trying to `destroy` the same element using Ajax. My code isn't working though. If I click my `<%= link_to %>` the element is removed but only when I refresh the page. This is the error shown in my console:

What am I doing wrong?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `ul' for #<#<Class:0x1085de6a8>:0x1085d8f78>):
1: $("#<%= ul.awardInfo(@award) %>").remove();
  app/views/awards/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_awards_destroy_js_erb___273185883_2217653740_0'
```

My `awards_controller`:

```
def create
  @award = Award.new(params[:award])
  if @award.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
      format.js { }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile)}
      format.js { render 'fail_create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @award = Award.find(params[:id])
  @award.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
    format.js {  }
  end
end
```

In `profiles/show.html.erb`:

```
<div id="awardList">
  <ul class="awardInfo">
    <%= render :partial => 'awards/award', :collection => @profile.awards, :locals => {:award_count => @profile.awards.length} %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In `awards/_award.html.erb`:

```
<li>-&nbsp;<%= award.body %>&nbsp;<%= link_to 'x', award_path(award), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove #{award.body}?" %></li>
```

In `awards/create.js.erb`:

```
$('ul.awardInfo').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@award)) %>");
```

In `awards/destroy.js.erb`:

```
$("#<%= ul.awardInfo(@award) %>").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you put ul.awardInfo also within the server side code.  I think you are looking for something as follows:

("#ul.awardInfo(<%=@award%>)").remove();

This will hopefully get you past the error.  But if it does not help you delete the exact award, consider using dom_id to generate unique ids.  You can see a great sample here: https://github.com/markusproske/ajax_demo/tree/jquery

Comment: That's not doing it, but I appreciate it. I followed the tutorial in the book *Beginning Rails 3* and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you paste samples of how the ids of the nodes you want to remove look like?  Give me examples of two nodes.